# How can I complete my calculator in Python with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have to make a calculator function with conditional statements in Python with Tkinter, I already have the design.

I tried saving the first number that is digited in a variable for later use, then I save the operator in anoter variable but I don't know how to save the second number.

Here's the code of the function:

```
    def btnClick(value):
        global val
        if value != "+" and value != "*" and value != "/" and value != "-" and value!= 
    "=" and value != "CE":
            val = val + str(value)
            box.set(val)
        else:
            op=val #op saves the operator in a variable
            val = val + str(value)
            n1= val[:-1]#saves the number minus the operator
            val = ""
            box.set(" ")
            val = val + str(value)
            n2= val
```

What happens is that the second value is not saved in n2 but in n1.

Comment: Could you write comments in-line explaining what your function does? I can’t decipher it. I’ve started an answer but I can’t finishing it without knowing why you are setting value `op=num` but never using it. Doing something odd with the `valor` string too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope my code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use `eval()`.
 Take the whole string of input from the user say `1+2`. Take this `value` from whatever widget you are using.Then in your function `btnClick` do:

```
def btnClick(value)  
    answer = eval(value)
```

Then set the answer to whatever widget you are using. 
`eval()` returns the result and takes string input.

Comment: That’s even easier! Using `eval` is dangerous but in this case you’re probably fine

Comment: I'm not allowed to use eval. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair bit of improvement that is possible but this should get you moving. It only accepts two values and then prints out the string representation. It does not do the actual math part though.

You could also store the entered values in a list then do a list comprehension once someone presses “=“ or “CE”.

```
def btnClick(value):
    global val1 = None
    global val2 = None
    if value not in [ "+", "*", "/", "-",  
"=", "CE"] :
        if val1 is None:
            val1 = value
        else:
            val2 = value
        valor = valor + str(value)
        box.set(valor)
    else:
        result = None
        if value == "+":
            result = val1 + val2
        elif value == "*":
            result = val1 * val2
        elif value == "/":
            result = val1 / val2
        elif value == "-":
            result = val1 - val2
        else:
            box.set("enter a valid operator")
        if result is not None:
            box.set(f"{value1} {value} {value2} = {result}")
```

Comment: I will create another global variable then